# Midnight lines in Pine Script 5

Tags: tradingview-api

Can anyone tell me how to make an indicator in Pine Script 5 that shows vertical lines on New York midnight. Ideally, a slightly wider line on Sunday night to show the start of the week.

All I can get to work at the moment is by using plot shape, but I want just vertical lines so I can specify 1 or 2 widths.

Would like the lines to continue into history too, not just the current week.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy and have a nice day

```
//This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © MY_Trade_Journey

//@version=5
indicator("Midnight Line",overlay = true)
changeofday = dayofweek != dayofweek[1]
if changeofday and dayofweek(time,"America/New_York") != dayofweek.sunday
    line.new(time,1,time,0,xloc=xloc.bar_time,width=2,extend=extend.both)

if changeofday and dayofweek(time,"America/New_York") == dayofweek.sunday
    line.new(time,1,time,0,xloc=xloc.bar_time,width=10,extend=extend.both,color=color.fuchsia)
```